# Can the complete graph $K_n$ ($n$ is even) be decomposed into a union of edge-disjoint $2$-regular graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

I apologize in advance, I might have used some wrong words, since English is not my mother tongue. Please, ask for clarification. If this is in wrong community, please suggest a better one for this kind of questions.

Can someone please guide me into understanding this question a little bit better?

With my limited understanding, I think the answer is no. I don't have a good explanation for that, excepting for trying to draw these graphs.

I'm very new into this subject, any help is much welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider counting edges. How many edges does one of the $2$-regular graphs have? How many edges does $K_n$ have? What can we conclude?

> Each piece in the decomposition is a $2$-regular graph with $n$ vertices, so it also has $n$ edges. The complete graph $K_n$ has $\binom n2 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges. So the decomposition must consist of $\frac{n-1}{2}$ graphs... which is a problem, because $\frac{n-1}{2}$ is not an integer.